# Find bounded solutions of this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

The function $y(x)$ satisfies the following ode:

$L[y]=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2\frac{dy}{dx})-x^2y= f(x)$

By substituting $y(x)=\frac{z(x)}{x}$ we can solve the homogeneous problem $(L[y]=0)$ and obtain the answer

$y(x)=\frac{Ae^x}{x}+\frac{Be^{-x}}{x}$.

How would you show that the solution given by $sinh(x)/x$ is bounded as $x \rightarrow 0$?

Furthermore how would you find a solution that remains bounded as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: I tried that $\frac{sinh(x)}{x}=A+B=0$ which I think may show that A and B are bounded.

Comment: I thought that maybe using the identity cosh(x)-sinh(x)=e^{-x} could be useful for the second bit.

Comment: $C\sinh(x) = \frac{C}{2}(e^x - e^{-x})$, so if you know that $A = -B = \frac{C}{2}$, then try finding the maximum of the function on $x > 0$, then show that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{C}{2}\left(\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{x}\right)$ exists.  My answer addresses the second question.

Comment: Sorry.  You can't just maximize on $x > 0$.  Just maximize on $(0,1]$, and then show the limit exists.  There is clearly no maximum on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, as the exponential term grows far too quickly.

Comment: My original hint ends up being a lot messier than I originally anticipated.  But in this case, you can use power series expansions to show that the limit exists.  I edited this into my answer, because it is clearer than giving a second hint of "use power series".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint on the first question:

$$f(x) = \frac{\sinh(x)}{x} = \frac{1}{2x}(e^x - e^{-x})$$

We can show that this function has limit at $x=0$ as follows:

$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$

$e^{-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n!}$

\begin{align*}\frac{\sinh(x)}{x} &= \frac{1}{2x} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2x} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-(-1)^n)\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&= \frac{1}{2x} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2 x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}
\end{align*}

So we conclude that
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sinh(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} = 1$$

This tells us that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = 1$, hence the function remains bounded as $x \to 0$.

Hint on the second question:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^x}{x} = +\infty$$
What this means is that any nonzero constant in front of the term $\frac{e^x}{x}$ will result in an unbounded solution as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: so the solution would be $C\frac{e^{-x}}{x}$

Comment: For the second one?  That's exactly right.